# Case sensitive URLs for sites created in Site.com

Tags: site.com

The question is pretty straight forward.

In our setup there's a difference with `http://www.mysite.com/Downloads` and `http://www.mysite.com/downloads`. It really shouldn't matter, but it seems to.

Is there a setting some where we need to change so the urls are not case sensitive?

Comment: Somehow never noticed this before, but that's decidedly inconvenient, especially when you're used to use a case insensitive programming language!

Comment: Yes, this should be a config option in future versions of Site.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no setting to make Site.com urls case insensitive.

The best you could do is use javascript in your 404 page to redirect to the all lower case URL or an alias.

Comment: All other answers essentially say the same thing, but you were the only one to really offer a solution. We can also alias the pages too, but it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: updated my answer to include the alias idea as well

Answer (score 5):

The url is made up of Force.com domain name (http://www.site.com), which is case **insensitive**, and then the path that identifies the specific site (/Downloads or /downloads). This path is case **sensitive** I am afraid, therefore `downloads` and `Downloads` are treated as different urls.

See this [article](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites) for more info. Search for `case sensitive` keyword on this page.

Anup

Comment: I think the question is about site.com not Visualforce sites. The same link may be applicable, but I'm not familiar enough with site.com to know.

Comment: The question is specific to site.com tools, not Visual Force. I'll check out the link anyways. Thanks.

Comment: The url rules are the same for Site.com and Force.com sites.